# teb_local_planner steering angle

Tags: ros, slam, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I'm new in the ROS environment and this community, so first of all I want to say Hello to everyone of you.

I want to setup an SLAM based autonomous car. The car should detect obstacle with the help of a Lidar sensor. I'am able to create a map of the environment and set an estimation point and a goal. For the navigation I use the navigation stack + the teb_local_planner. There I have some troubles with the MAP update because I have only a Pentium Processor in the notebook. But maybe I can fix this problem with bette configuraions. My problem as soon as I got a path I have to send the moving commands to my car. For that I have a raspberry pi on the car who will forward a steering angle and a speed value to my motor management. But I don't know in wich topic the teb_local_planner publish these topics.

If you need more information tell what I have to publish to you.

Many thanks and I look forward to your answers :)

Best,
Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248371/teb_local_planner-steering-angle/) by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?distro=kinetic) the result is output to the topic cmd_vel (arrow on the bottom of the image on the move_base webpage ) as a geometry_msgs/Twist message .

I haven't used a car-like kinematic myself, but I just found this page http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Planning%20for%20car-like%20robots with more details for the teb planner and ackermann kinematics.

The sections 2.2.1 and 2.2.2. could interest you.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1